# How can i search MS Graph API for toRecipients

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

i am trying to to get email via graph APi based on the toRecipients . Is that posible or is it still only avail via search and not filter ?

I tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages?$select=sender,subject,toRecipients&filter=(toRecipients/emailAddress/address) eq 'test@demo.com'
```

which generates the blow error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "25583e87-66da-477b-a1be-0a0fd0371349",
            "date": "2020-04-21T20:01:39"
        }
    }
}
```

i also tried To instead of toRecipients but that doesnt work eithet.

Answer (score -3):

Can you try the following? Note the `$filter` query parameter.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages?$select=sender,subject,toRecipients&$filter=(toRecipients/emailAddress/address) eq 'test@demo.com'
```

Comment: This creates an error when using this filter {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1ff9bb7e-72ce-4db1-beed-9c524ba24986",
            "date": "2020-04-22T06:56:43"
        }
    } The parent value for a property access of a property 'emailAddress' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.